# Combination of Elements with by Using Array

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

Goal:
Make a combination of the element by using the input data. The goal is to achieve the output.

```
An example      

Current situation (input):      
jim west    aaa 12345
Le tomo     bbb 
Sara brown      

Requested Result(output):       
jim west    aaa 12345
Le tomo     aaa 12345
Sara brown  aaa 12345
jim west    bbb 
Le tomo     bbb 
Sara brown  bbb 

-------------------------------

Another example     

Current situation (input):      
jim west    aaa 12345
Le tomo     bbb 32154
Sara brown  ccc 78946

Requested Result(output):       
jim west    aaa 12345
Le tomo     aaa 12345
Sara brown  aaa 12345
jim west    bbb 32154
Le tomo     bbb 32154
Sara brown  bbb 32154
jim west    ccc 78946
Le tomo     ccc 78946
Sara brown  ccc 78946

-------------------------------

Another example

Current situation (input):              
jim west    aaa 12345
Le tomo     
Sara brown      

Requested Result(output):       
jim west    aaa 12345
Le tomo     aaa 12345
Sara brown  aaa 12345
```

Problem:
*I don't know how to solve it. Do you have any advice about what path I should use?

Info:
*I was unable to use permutation in this context.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] column1 = { "jim west", "Le tomo", "Sara brown" };
        string[] column2 = { "aaa", "bbb"};
        string[] column3 = { "12345" };



    }
}
```

Comment: Please improve your question. Provide the example data not as image, provide the expected output or a similar content.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea of what you're asking. You have 11k reputation, I'd assume you know how to ask a question by now.

Comment: Please inform me if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This code will create the result in the examples:

```
{
            var result = new List<string[]>();

            string[] column1 = { "jim west", "Le tomo", "Sara brown" };
            string[] column2 = { "aaa", "bbb" };
            string[] column3 = { "12345" };

            foreach(string c1 in column1)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < column2.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] toAdd = { c1, column2[i], column3.Length> i ? column3[i] : ""  };
                    result.Add(toAdd);
                }
            }
```

The reason for using for instead of foreach is that the colums2 and colums3 are linked together in the examples. If they should not be linked together; 3 nested foreach will do the trick like this:

```
    var result = new List<string[]>();

    string[] column1 = { "jim west", "Le tomo", "Sara brown" };
    string[] column2 = { "aaa", "bbb" };
    string[] column3 = { "12345" };

    foreach(string c1 in column1)
    {

        foreach(string c2 in column2)
        {
            foreach(string c3 in column3)
            {
                string[] toAdd = { c1, c2, c3 };
                result.Add(toAdd);
            }
        }
    }
```